# 'registerForActivityResult' not resolved in Activity but works in AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

'''

```
multiPermissionsLauncher = **registerForActivityResult**(multiplePermissionsContracts,isGranted ->{
            if(isGranted.containsValue(false)){
                multipermissionsLauncher.launch(permissions);}
});
```

'''
This works if I use it with AppCompatActivity,but is not recognized in regular activity class.

Comment: because its part of AppCompatActivity or any activity type that is extended from that and not the base Activity type